# Sufficient condition of existence of Killing field on Riemannian manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, isometry

As in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992636/existence-of-killing-field) , I know there are some Riemannian manifold which there is not Killing field on it . But it is not obvious that the sufficient condition of existence of Killing field. And I Google it , seemly, there is not paper talk about the sufficient condition of existence of Killing field. What paper is about this ?

Comment: The existence of a Killing field is equivalent to the existence of a nontrivial action of $\Bbb R$ by isometries.

Comment: @MikeMiller  I know that . But I think ,  study the existence of nontrivial action  is harder than of Killing field.  And in other hand , seemly,the existence of  harmonic 1-form symmetric to the one of Killing field.